# Release UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<UInt8> values

Tags: swift, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, swift2

I am implementing a pure Swift `NSData` alternative. Below is part of my Swift 2 code. As far as I know, `Data` instance deinitialization does not `destroy()` and `dealloc()` bytes the `block` buffer points to.
So, are there any ways of calling `destroy` and `dealloc()` on buffer pointers to prevent memory leaks before the `Data` instance deinitializes?

```
public struct Data: DataContainer {
    public typealias Block = UInt8
    public var blocks: UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Block>

    public init(bytes: UnsafeMutablePointer<Block>, length: Int) {
        // copy bytes
        let bytesCopy = UnsafeMutablePointer<Block>.alloc(length)
        bytesCopy.initializeFrom(bytes, count: length)
        // init byte blocks
        self.blocks = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Block>(start: bytesCopy, count: length)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve this by using a `class` for the actual implementation.
An example how this can be done is given in 
[Friday Q&A 2015-04-17: Let's Build Swift.Array](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-04-17-lets-build-swiftarray.html):

> Destruction can be solved by using a `class`, which provides `deinit`. The
>   pointer can be destroyed there. `class` doesn't have value semantics,
>   but we can solve this by using `class` for the implementation of the
>   `struct`, and exposing the `struct` as the external interface to the
>   array. This looks something like:
>
> ```
> class ArrayImpl<T> {
>     var ptr: UnsafeMutablePointer<T>
>
>     deinit {
>         ptr.destroy(...)
>         ptr.dealloc(...)
>     }
> }
>
> struct Array<T> {
>     var impl: ArrayImpl<T>
> }
> ```
>
> You then write methods on `Array` that forward to implementations on
>   `ArrayImpl`, where the real work is done.

Applying this approach to your problem could roughly look like this:

```
private class DataImpl {
    typealias Block = UInt8
    var blocks: UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Block>

    init(bytes: UnsafeMutablePointer<Block>, length: Int) {
        // copy bytes
        let bytesCopy = UnsafeMutablePointer<Block>.alloc(length)
        bytesCopy.initializeFrom(bytes, count: length)
        // init byte blocks
        self.blocks = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Block>(start: bytesCopy, count: length)
    }

    deinit {
        print("deinit")
        blocks.baseAddress.destroy(blocks.count)
        blocks.baseAddress.dealloc(blocks.count)
    }
}

struct Data {
    typealias Block = UInt8
    private var impl : DataImpl

    init(bytes: UnsafeMutablePointer<Block>, length: Int) {
        impl = DataImpl(bytes: bytes, length: length)
    }
}
```

A simple test shows that this works as expected, the data is released
when the variable goes out of scope:

```
var bytes : [UInt8] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
do {
    let data = Data(bytes: &bytes, length: bytes.count)
}
print("finished")
```

Output:

```
deinit
finished
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer helped me save my time

Comment: @b1nary: You are welcome. – Btw, instead of your own memory allocation, you could alternatively use an `[UInt8]` array as the backing store, then the deallocation is handled automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [@Martin R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1187415/martin-r) for his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32441432/release-unsafemutablebufferpointeruint8-values/32441859#32441859).
I've added `class AutoreleasingMutableBufferPointer<T>` as container and deallocator of `struct UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<T>`.
Here is the working code:

```
public class AutoreleasingMutableBufferPointer<T> {
    public var buffer: UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<T>

    public init(start pointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<T>, count length: Int) {
        self.buffer = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<T>(start: pointer, count: length)
    }

    public init(buffer: UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<T>) {
        self.buffer = buffer
    }

    deinit {
        self.buffer.baseAddress.destroy(buffer.count)
        self.buffer.baseAddress.dealloc(buffer.count)
    }
}

public struct Data: DataContainer {
    public typealias Block = UInt8
    public var blocks: AutoreleasingMutableBufferPointer<Block>
}

extension Data {
    public init(bytes: UnsafeMutablePointer<Block>, length: Int) {
        let bytesCopy = UnsafeMutablePointer<Block>.alloc(length)
        bytesCopy.initializeFrom(bytes, count: length)
        self.blocks = AutoreleasingMutableBufferPointer<Block>(start: bytesCopy, count: length)
    }
}
```

Comment: As you are *copying* the data in `Data` constructor, there is no need to require a *mutable* pointer as argument, I would define it as `public init(bytes: UnsafePointer<Block>, length: Int)`. Then you can create a `Data` even from a constant array: `let bytes : [UInt8] = [1, 2, 3, 4]; let data = Data(bytes: bytes, length: bytes.count)`.